# Change SKU dynamically in configurable product for Magento 2.4

Tags: configurable-product, magento-community, product-page, magento2.4.3

Does anybody know how to implement changing of the SKU on configurable product page according to variation selection, for Magento 2.4.3?

Thanks!

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/switch-product-sku-according-selection-child-products-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks but I already tried it and it doesn't work. I suppose it's for an older version of Magento and I can't figure out how to adapt it for 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display product SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing **SKU** for each simple product.

Switching **SKU** when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This is what I did and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For shops, which are using a Hyvä Theme, our module might be an option:

https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/customgento-module-child-product-data.html

This updates not only the SKU, but also the following attributes quick and easy:

- Product Name
- Short Description
- Description
- “More Information” Block
- Related Products (performantly via AJAX)
- Upsell Products (performantly via AJAX)

You only need to enter the fitting identifiers of your Hyvä theme in the system configuration, and the module will do the rest.